# What other wallet service has integrated a message attach feature like public notes used in blockchain.info wallets?

Tags: blockchain.info, public-note

What other block explorers or wallets that has integrated a public note feature like blockchain.info? I'm looking to attach messages to transactions.

Comment: just found out that blockchain.info removed the public note feature and only has private notes. i don't know why it was removed. if anyone finds out why, please post here.